# Why can't I launch Ubuntu in a computer with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 two weeks ago in my new laptop. The laptop has Windows 10 so I decided to keep both OSes. It worked properly until last week, when it started to launch Windows automatically, and no longer asks me to choose an OS to boot.

How can I enter Ubuntu?

Comment: Windows often does updates & resets system to make it first in boot order. A major update to grub also makes it first in boot order. You just have to manage what system boots normally. What brand/model system? Can you boot 'Ubuntu' entry in UEFI one time boot menu? Same key as you used to boot live installer often f12.

Comment: You should change the boot order from the Firmware settings and make Ubuntu 1st. You can access it through one-time boot menu (`F12` usually) or directly by some other key (`F2` for my dell)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) That may help even though *installing* Windows isn't what caused the problem in your case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot into Windows.
2. Go to Start Menu (Windows icon) --> Power --> Select "Restart" while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
3. Go to Troubleshoot --> UEFI Firmware settings.
4. The system will reboot and you will be allowed to go to the *Firmware Settings* (If not press the appropriate key, some common are <kbd>DEL</kbd>,<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd>. Alternatively, go to "One-time Boot Menu" (Usually <kbd>F12</kbd> and select the appropriate option to go into "Firmware Settings").
5. There should be something like "*Boot Sequence*" in there (Firmware settings change depending on the Motherboard).
6. Make sure "Ubuntu" is 1st in the boot order. (Above Windows boot manager)
7. Save and exit. (Sometimes <kbd>F10</kbd> does this)